# Firebase Messaging getToken() throws: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I get the error "**Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined**" if I call the method `getToken()`, but only on my work notebook.
On my pesonal PC it is working.

Here is my code in the web app created via TypeScript:

```
this.messaging.requestPermission()
.then(() => {
  console.log('Notification permission granted!');
  return me.messaging.getToken();  ==> Here I get the error on my work notebook!
})
.then(messagingToken=> {
  me.updateMessagingToken(messagingToken);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
  me.openSnackBar("Unable to get permission to notify!" + err);
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you may have cached older version of your app. Have you tried (1) clearing the cache, (2) using private mode, (3) using another browser?